# How to add Login functionality to Angular app that reads credentials from JSON-SERVER?

Tags: angular, json-server

I am creating an Angular app that users will need to be able to log into.

Currently, I have a Service that sends HTTP Requests to performs CRUD operations on an `Employee.json` file using [JSON-SERVER](https://github.com/typicode/json-server).

I want the user to enter their Employee ID and password (they will have previously provided this info).

Then the app should search `Employee.json` to see if there is a match. If 
there's a match, log them in

I'm just wondering what is the best way to go about adding the login feature to my app?

Comment: Is security a concern? If so, you might want to look beyond json-server.

Comment: @nullptr.t Hi, yes it would be eventually. Would it be a better option now to just get the login functionality working, or should I look for something other than json-server? If so, what would you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you're planning on having any security at all in the future, I would recommend skipping json-server all together and go for a more solid back-end solution that has plenty of libraries for securing your API. You can roll you own API with something like Node (Using the express library) and use JWT tokens to secure it. Or you can go with something like Firebase (A product by google) which essentially manages all the login functionality, user creation, security, etc. for you.